# NextJs + supabase not deploying supabaseUrl is required

Tags: next.js, vercel, supabase

i'm trying to deploy my project but i keep getting this error saying that supabaseUrl is required.

I'm getting this error
[image]

This is my supabaseClient.js

import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

```
const supabaseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL;
const supabaseAnonKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY;

export const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey);
```

And this is my `.env.local` file

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL=https://uee...
NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY=ey...VU
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID=75...09
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_SECRET=46...a
REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:3000
```

When i run `vercel build` and then `vercel prod --prebuilt` it works fine. Also, i added the supabaseUrl and supabase anon key to the environment variables at project settings in vercel dashboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vercel production deployment gets .env variables from `.env.production` file, also you can manually set up .env variables from settings.
[image]

Comment: I had already done that, but i changed SUPABASE_URL to NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL and it worked! Thanks